# How to remove the time from the datetime in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have an epoch:

```
1625803200000
```

I'm then converting it to a readable format using:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],unit='ms')
```

Which returns:

```
2021-07-09 04:00:00
```

The time isn't relevant, so I'm trying to remove it. When I do:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'][:-6],unit='ms')
```

It returns `NaT`

How do I only return the date?

It's inside a pandas data frame, not sure if that's relevant. Sorry for the noob question!

Comment: With a regular Python `datetime` you can just call `date` on it, but the Pandas version requires you to go through some gyrations.  See linked dupe.

Comment: Thanks Sam the linked duped solved my issue